# how can I update sql server table with new data from an excel sheet?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have managed to get data from an excel sheet into my SQL SERVER table through VB.net but every time I run the query (click the button), the same data is uploaded again to my table. Is there a way to import only the additional data ? (column 'Email' should be unique in my SQLSERVER table) Below is my code:

Thank you for your help !

```
 Dim ExcelConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Excel.xlsm;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=No""")
        ExcelConnection.Open()

        Dim expr As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"

        Dim objCmdSelect As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(expr, ExcelConnection)
        Dim objDR As OleDb.OleDbDataReader

        Dim SQLconn As New SqlConnection()
        Dim ConnString As String = "Data Source=USER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=SSPI"
        SQLconn.ConnectionString = ConnString
        SQLconn.Open()


        Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(SQLconn)
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TableName"

            Try
                objDR = objCmdSelect.ExecuteReader
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDR)
                objDR.Close()
                SQLconn.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End Using
```

Comment: Is your EMAil field just an unique index or is a primarykey?

Answer (score 0):

If your EMail field is just an Unique Index then you could change the property

```
`Ignore Duplicate Key`
```

and set its value to Yes on the property page for the Index definition (Sql Management Studio).
In this way SqlBulkCopy will try to add, but in case of duplicates the record will be discarded without problems. This property settings is equivalen to the [INDEX_OPTION IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186869.aspx)

Another option, with less side effects, but a bit more complex, is to add your values in a temporary table and prepare a stored procedure that copies the records from the temporary table into the final one checking the insert for duplicates. (I haven't tried this)

Comment: Hi Steve, yes it is a unique index.. I was thinking of creating a procedure but if there was a simpler way, I would go with it... Will try your ignore idea duplicate key. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add another column to your excel named something like UploadDate so after each import you just update this column in excel and you’re good.

You’ll have to update your SELECT query to something like “SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE UploadDate is null”

If you don’t have a ton of data then you might not need to use bulk import. In that case you can easily generate insert statements that look like this.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from tableName where email = @email)
    INSERT (column1, column2,...) values (val1, val2,...)
```

And execute bunch of these at once.